# Is the file accessed by an other application

Tags: java, file-io, concurrency

I'd like to know if it were possible, in java, to fire an event when an external application modifies the content of a given text file

I'm just trying to program a little software that automatically synchronizes a local file to a remote ftp server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try this lib [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net)

**More Info :**

Download JNotify from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnotify/files/jnotify/jnotify-0.93/jnotify-lib-0.93.zip/download)

Extract the zip, put .dll/.so according to platform in your lib path. and create a class provide `jnotify-0.93.jar` in class path.

Sample code:

```
package org.life.java.stackoverflow.questions;

import net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotify;
import net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotifyListener;

/**
 *
 * @author Jigar
 */
public class JNotifyDemo {

    public void sample() throws Exception {
        // path to watch
        String path = System.getProperty("user.home");

        // watch mask, specify events you care about,
        // or JNotify.FILE_ANY for all events.
        int mask = JNotify.FILE_CREATED
                | JNotify.FILE_DELETED
                | JNotify.FILE_MODIFIED
                | JNotify.FILE_RENAMED;

        // watch subtree?
        boolean watchSubtree = true;

        // add actual watch
        int watchID = JNotify.addWatch(path, mask, watchSubtree, new Listener());

        // sleep a little, the application will exit if you
        // don't (watching is asynchronous), depending on your
        // application, this may not be required
        Thread.sleep(1000000);

        // to remove watch the watch
        boolean res = JNotify.removeWatch(watchID);
        if (!res) {
            // invalid watch ID specified.
        }
    }

    class Listener implements JNotifyListener {

        public void fileRenamed(int wd, String rootPath, String oldName,
                String newName) {
            print("renamed " + rootPath + " : " + oldName + " -> " + newName);
        }

        public void fileModified(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
            print("modified " + rootPath + " : " + name);
        }

        public void fileDeleted(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
            print("deleted " + rootPath + " : " + name);
        }

        public void fileCreated(int wd, String rootPath, String name) {
            print("created " + rootPath + " : " + name);
        }

        void print(String msg) {
            System.err.println(msg);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new JNotifyDemo().sample();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar: LOCALS~1\Temp\etilqs_4s8ywsvyukghK0uDxRop
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : LOCALS~1\Temp\etilqs_4s8ywsvyukghK0uDxRop
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : LOCALS~1\Temp\output1295531079119
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
deleted C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001ea9
created C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001eae
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : LOCALS~1\Temp\etilqs_04gchL79ZJrpClZIqiom
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : LOCALS~1\Temp\etilqs_04gchL79ZJrpClZIqiom
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001eae
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001eae
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : LOCALS~1\Temp\output1295531079119
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Current Session
deleted C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001ea8
created C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001eaf
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : LOCALS~1\Temp\etilqs_04gchL79ZJrpClZIqiom
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : LOCALS~1\Temp\etilqs_04gchL79ZJrpClZIqiom
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001eaf
modified C:\Documents and Settings\jigar : Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_001eaf
```

Comment: Plateform dependent but it does the job I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll need to monitor this yourself on a continual basis, either by checking the date the file was modified or doing a hash of the contents (checksum, etc).  In general, there's no event-driven Java-generic feedback from the underlying O/S, so if there's any possible additional support, it will be O/S dependent.

Any libraries in Java that do support this are essentially doing this on their own.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a thread poll the file every few seconds and check its modification time.

Also, it's good to know that Java 7 has the [WatchService API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html):

> The WatchService API is designed for applications that need to be notified about file change events.

Here is a post on it: [Java 7: WatchService for File Change Notification](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/08/java-7-watchservice-for-file-change.html)